# Making a C program take in a plain text file at execution time

Tags: c, file, struct

I have an assignment that is requiring that my program takes in a plain text file at execution time and manipulates it to keep track of a vending machine inventory.

The file has to contain 12 rows with the details of each item in the machine that is used to populate data structs.

Would passing the file to the program require command line arguments or is it something different?

I am using a GCC compiler.

I have tried adding the address of the file to the execution command but nothing came of that.

Comment: command line argument or a predefined filename

Comment: You only need a commmand-line argument if you want the filename to be flexible. Otherwise, a hard-coded filename would be sufficient, for example `fp = fopen( "inventory.txt", "r+" );`.

Comment: _I have tried adding the address of the file to the execution command but nothing came of that._ What does this mean? Edit your question and show your code if the previous comments didn't clear things up.

Comment: "*Would passing the file to the program require command line arguments"* Require, no.

Comment: **I have tried adding the address of the file to the execution command but nothing came of that."* Well, maybe you should ask about that *code*. Check out what is a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I've assumed you need the file path to be accepted as an input to the program.

If so then it depends on how you would like to pass this information to the program, but I'm not convinced that passing command line arguments could be considered an runtime input from user. However you could pass a path to the file as an command line argument, and access it using `argc` and `argv` arguments of the `main` function :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  //argv[0] is always name of the program
  //argv[1] is the first command line argument 
  //and so on up to argc-1 (argv[argc-1]  is the last argument) 
  //so, in the simplest form do:
  if (argc < 2) return -1; // check if any argument was passed, as pm100 said in comments to this answer.  
  FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "rb"); // change "rb" to mode you need
  if (f==NULL) return -1; // file could not be opened

  // process the file as you need from here
  ...
}
```

The alternative approach, reading user input **at runtime** using `fgets` could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-do-i-read-a-string-entered-by-the-user-in-c). Then pass the string you got from user as an first argument to `fopen`.
You can, of course, mix these two approaches (checking if any command-line args were passed, and if not ask for user input) but this probably would be an overkill for a homework.

If you just need to load file from a fixed place in your filesystem, and filename won't change then simply change `argv` from my example to your filename or path:

```
int main()
{
  const char filename[] = "your_file_name_here";
  FILE *f = fopen(filename, "rb"); // change "rb" to mode you need
  if (f==NULL) return -1; // file could not be opened

  // process the file as you need from here
  ...
}
```

Comment: make sure argc > 1 in the cli case

Comment: Yes, you are right.